# A disc burner wasn't found (MacBook Pro Boot Camp)

Tags: windows-8.1, dvd, boot-camp, burning

I'm running Windows 8.1 on a MacBook Pro (early 2011 15 inch) with the Boot Camp drivers installed. My DVD-R is identified in the Device Manager as a "MATSHITA DVD-R", and I want to burn an ISO file to a writeable DVD.

To try this I selected the "Burn Disk Image" menu item from the context menu in Explorer:

[image: Win8 Context Menu]

...and encountered this message: "A disc burner wasn't found. Make sure that a burner is installed properly..." etc.

[image: A disc burner wasn't found]

The devices function properly when the MacBook is running OS X.

How could I get this to work under Win8.1, though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just found the solution [here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/a-disc-burner-wasnt-found-make-sure-that-a-burner/96b4d634-0212-4e14-9cc7-62647c9cf5dd):

1. Open an elevated cmd window:

   `Win Key` > type **cmd** > right click on the **Command Prompt** result and choose **Run as administrator**.
2. Open Task Manager and End all Explorer tasks:

   `Ctrl + Shift + Esc` > right click **Windows Explorer** and choose **End task**.
3. Now in those elevated cmd window launch explorer:

   Just type **explorer.exe** and hit `Enter`.
4. After Explorer is up, navigate to your .ISO and try choosing "Burn Disk Image" for it again, now it should work.
5. You should not run Explorer this way, so once done with disc burning - reboot the PC or end all Explorer tasks and restart it again under your normal account.